# php procedural file and folder structure

Tags: php, html, web

i would like to know the best way or best practise for structuring procedural php programming, in uni i learnt to have folders for each section like an "admin" "products" etc folder for each part of the website, and each of my folders had a index.php where all the php code went, is that a good way to do it? or even the right way?

Are you meant to have multiple index files in multiple folders?

I dont know i just look online and see so many different ways but no one ever explains right from wrong or good from bad etc.

Comment: There is no "the right way" - do what *you* prefer

Comment: Well thats what i thought but just wanting to confirm really

Comment: most important thing is to keep inside the public folders of your web server just the bare minimum: your `index.php` files and all css/js/images (obvious), but the rest (auxiliary, configuration or function/class files) outside it. That way even in the case of a webserver misconfiguration an attacker will not be able to get your mysql password (for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking yes, you should try to separate your files into folders according to their functionality.

Please read the PSR-0 autoloading standard. I think it will help you to understand better why it's better to organize your code one way or another.

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md